# xamarin android send cuurent location to mysql database

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to send current user location coordinates (LatLong) automatically to mysql database using webservices with update every 5 seconds,, and in another app get the coordinates from mysql to plot markers on map. can anyone give me sample tutorial or project or example or any help, I am new in xamarin

Answer (score 0):

You should use a plugin for this purpose. This plugin is called [Geolocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator).

You can see their documentation [here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/).
Your source code [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin).

And you can get the location every 5 seconds as follows:

```cs
using Plugin.Geolocator;

var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync (timeoutMilliseconds: 5000);

Console.WriteLine ("Position Status: {0}", position.Timestamp);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Latitude: {0}", position.Latitude);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Longitude: {0}", position.Longitude);
```

And if you are continuously monitoring a user’s location, such as for a maps application, you can also tap into the PositionChanged event to receive updated coordinates:

```cs
locator.PositionChanged += (sender, e) => {
var position = e.Position;

latitudeLabel.Text = position.Latitude;
longitudeLabel.Text = position.Longitude;
};
```

For more information see this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/).

For render maps options you can see this [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/)

Comment: thank you for help, its very helpful, but I want to store user LatLong to mysql to reuse . how do that

Comment: You have added a tag of xamarin.forms and you are asking for information about MySQL, I think you should change the tags of your question. If this really helped, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: sorry about that mistake and thank you for help, please tell me how to send current location coordinates to mysql database, this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

This link is all you need :

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

Also after API-24 runtime permissions are required which you will find here

https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/